# Decode utc8 character from string Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm unable to decode the utc8 characters from string.

Below line getting from API

```
replace the cable if a fault is found â for example
```

actual string

```
replace the cable if a fault is found - for example
```

Can any one help me how to fix this ?

Thanks!!!

Comment: It's UTF-8, not utc8. What do you want to do with this UTF-8 string? Where do you see this minus sign?

Comment: i doubt they are decoding from a string either if the characters are UTF-8

Comment: Dart and Flutter use UTF-8 internally, so you should have no problems encoding this string or decoding it from a properly encoded UTF-8 source. We are going to need more context (such as a code sample and a description of where this string is actually coming from) to figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: OP is getting mojibake (the little a with a caret is an indicator).  Somewhere upstream of this string, somebody lied about the encoding.

Comment: Dart and Flutter actually use UTF16 internally, not UTF8.  Although there are converters for UTF8 reading and writing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Charset Detector [Flutter Charset Detector Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_charset_detector) to convert it to the correct encoding.

I already used it, and it works perfectly. You just have to convert the body of the response to the desired encoding.

You pass the bodyBytes field to the package autoDecode method.

```
Uint8List bodyBytes = response.bodyBytes;
DecodingResult decoded = (await CharsetDetector.autoDecode(bodyBytes));
String charset = decoded.charset;
String bodyInRightEncodage = decoded.string;
```

The response field is a [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) response object.

Comment: I'm getting response as json format. So i'm doing **jsonDecode(response.body)** because it is List<dynamic> . In this list somewhere im getting UTC-8 format. So how do i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Below line is working fine

```
jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes, allowMalformed: true));
```